# Fatal error: Class 'stdClass' not found codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I recently uploaded my codeigniter project to the live server and it shows the following error.but it is working fine on my local server.

> Fatal error: Class 'stdClass' not found in /home/public_html/system/database/drivers/mysqli/mysqli_result.php on line 183

Comment: which version of CI you are using?. Also check the php.ini for `extension=mysqli.so` on live server

Comment: CI 3 and if i try to connect using mysql or pdo instead of mysqli geting same error.but i change php 5.6 to 5.5,it is working

Comment: add a `$varnamehere = new stdClassNameHere;` at the top of the code. You're not declaring it maybe?

Answer (score 6):

This could be solved using either

```
use \stdClass
```

or

```
$my_obj = new \stdClass();
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

if you use a namespaces you must write `new \stdClass()`