# Class 'Public_Controller' not found in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

Same code is run properly in localhost but on server its show error
An uncaught Exception was encountered
Type: Error

Message: Class 'Public_Controller' not found

Filename: /home/referralearn/public_html/techmaa.org/portal/application/controllers/Auth.php

Line Number: 4

Backtrace:

File: /home/referralearn/public_html/techmaa.org/portal/index.php
Line: 314
Function: require_once

help me to solve this

Comment: It seems to be a syntax error calling the controller or something wrong with the file name

Post your Auth.php code (at least the first lines, where the error seems to be placed) so can check the syntax

Comment: please show us the **essential part** of the code causing your problem. Anyway this might be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41973248/fatal-error-class-stdclass-not-found-codeigniter

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.